# Unable to change Alt_R key using xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

I've been trying to change the key mapping of my keyboard for certain keys. So far I've been successful to do it using xmodmap for a variety of keys. However, no matter what I do, I can't get the Alt_R (the right side Alt key) which has a key code of 108 to map to the Up key. Here's the command I'm using:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Up"
```

Is there anything more that I need to do to get this working. Even after these changes, whenever I hit the Alt_R key, it ends up minimizing the current window.

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 0):

using xmodmap like you did above worked for me. My assumption is that Alt_R may be assigned to the function of minimizing windows somewhere and that the system doesn't forward the keypress to the Terminal after this. Have you checked the system shortcuts or maybe in compiz? Not sure if there is a compiz-module to minimze windows via a shortcut though.